# Handling a 401 response with sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm making an async url request with the new iOS 5 method: sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:. This uses a block to handle the response, but no NSURLConnectionDelegate delegate methods are being called? I can't see a way to set the delegate for the NSUrlConnection class in this instance?

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

   NSLog(@"HTTP response code: %i", httpResponse.statusCode);

   if (error != nil) {
       NSLog(@"There was error with the synchronous request: %@", error.description);              
   }
}];
```

The reason I need the delegate methods is because one of my calls gets a 401 response, which iOS handles in a different way - deferring authentication to delegate methods. When a 401 response comes back - httpResponse.statusCode is just "0".

Is there a way to stop iOS from trying to handle a 401 differently? In particular, I'm thinking I need to use the continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge: delegate method - but no delegates are being called in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Use one of the connection methods with a delegate, like initWithRequest:delegate:

Comment: Have a look at this answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828060/authentication-with-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequest-with-completion-hand

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a NSURLConnection instance and use a delegate for that. The `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is a shortcut for the same but with the default behavior without a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] nitWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

use the above method this will fire the delegates methods.