# sendAsynchronousRequest was deprecated in iOS 9, How to alter code to fix

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

Below is my code I am getting the issue with:

```
func parseFeedForRequest(request: NSURLRequest, callback: (feed: RSSFeed?, error: NSError?) -> Void)
{
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            callback(feed: nil, error: error)
        }
        else
        {
            self.callbackClosure = callback

            let parser : NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false
            parser.parse()
        }
    }
}
```

This is now deprecated as of iOS 9, and is telling me to use dataTaskWithRequest instead. Can someone help me change sendAsync with dataTask, I don't know how to.

Comment: I thought NSURLConnection was deprecated in iOS8. You should be using NSURLSession since iOS7.

Comment: What's the issue? Do you have trouble understanding [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLSession/dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:)?

Comment: Yes, I do not know how to convert this to use dataTaskWtihReqeust, I do not know what I need to change.

Comment: I agree with DarkDust, NSURSession is pretty straight forward to understand. Take a look at Ray's tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Comment: Patronizing me won't help how ever, I am new to swift and prefer to see answers then have eureka moments when I see what you did. I will take a look however this is Objectvice-C, know of any tutorials in swift?

Comment: You've been answering Swift questions for half a year now. Really, you need to learn to read the documentation, it's all there. That's a soft skill you will need as a developer. Your method already has all the types you need to make the call to `dataTaskWithRequest`, all you need to do is replace replace the call of `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` with the call of `NSURLSession.sharedSession.dataTaskWithRequest`. It doesn't get much easier.

Comment: Please search SO, here is great answer to your Swift need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040893/how-to-use-nsurlsessiondatatask-in-swift

Comment: Thank you for the answers, plus @DarkDust I appreciate where you are coming from, and I will correct myself, I am amateur, I may have been doing it for half a year but for half and hour a week, practically a beginner. I was simply referring to the "Oh Come on", it seemed unnecessary for you to help me with my search.

Comment: You're right, my tone was unnecessary, sorry about that. I just believe this issue is so simple that you should (no, _must_) be able to solve it yourself and that you'll learn a bigger lesson solving it yourself. In the 20mins this discussion is going on you should have been able to find the solution :-) (Plus, the solution can already be found on SO already, as @JosipB. pointed out.)

Comment: @DarkDust well thank you for the time taken to help me, I shall take note for next time I need to figure something out.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use `NSURLSession` instead like below,

For Objective-C

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:"YOUR URL"]
          completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                              NSURLResponse *response,
                              NSError *error) {
            // handle response

  }] resume];
```

For Swift,

```
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "YOUR URL")!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var params = ["username":"username", "password":"password"] as Dictionary<String, String>

    request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        print("Response: \(response)")})

    task.resume()
```

For asynchronously query, from Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/)

> Like most networking APIs, the NSURLSession API is highly
>   asynchronous. It returns data in one of two ways, depending on the
>   methods you call:
>
> To a completion handler block that returns data to your app when a
>   transfer finishes successfully or with an error.
>
> By calling methods on your custom delegate as the data is received.
>
> By calling methods on your custom delegate when download to a file is
>   complete.

Comment: How do you make sure that the request runs asynchronously?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff, I just updated my answer. Please let me know if you still have any query.

Comment: I get an error at the &err statement: Extra argument 'error' in call

Comment: hello Nilesh, Find me on Linkedin on this link..https://www.linkedin.com/in/khushal-patel-6108537b/

Answer (score 16):

Swift implementation

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

}
```

Comment: Don't forget you need to call `resume()` on your `dataTaskWithRequest` or it won't do anything.

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3.0

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.com")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let session = URLSession.shared

session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
    print("Entered the completionHandler")
}.resume()
```

Answer (score 9):

This is the swift 2.1 version:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "YOUR URL")!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let params = ["username":"username", "password":"password"] as Dictionary<String, String>

request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
print("Response: \(response)")})

task.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Apples dev env is starting to be confusing. Everything is outdated!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 2.0:**

Old (replace with New below):

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue()) { (response, data, error) -> Void in

// Code

}
```

New:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in

// Code

}
task.resume()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4**

```
let params = ["email":"email@email.com", "password":"123456"] as Dictionary<String, String>

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/api/1/login")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in

    do {
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        print(json)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }

})

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

with swift 3.1

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: image_url_string)! as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let params = ["username":"username", "password":"password"] as Dictionary<String, String>

    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: [])

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        print("Response: \(String(describing: response))")})

    task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Illustrating with an example, the alternative code to the deprecation of:

> sendAsynchronousRequest(_:queue:completionHandler:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]

Tested and works in Swift 2.1 onwards.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var theImage: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let url = NSURL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg")


        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("thers an error in the log")
            } else {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.theImage.image = image

                }
            }

        }

        task.resume()

    }

}
```

//Displays an image on the ViewControllers ImageView. Connect an outlet of the ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SWIFT3.0 Version of [Nilesh Patel's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30935460/4131763) with JSONSerialised data

```
let url = URL(string: "<HERE GOES SERVER API>")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST" //GET OR DELETE etc....
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("<ValueforAuthorization>", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            let parameter = [String:Any]() //This is your parameters [String:Any]
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameter, options: .prettyPrinted)
                // here "jsonData" is the dictionary encoded in JSON data
                request.httpBody = jsonData
                let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (incomingData, response, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        print(request)
                    }else if let response = response {
                        print(response)
                    }else if let incomingData = incomingData {
                        print(incomingData)
                    }
                })
                task.resume()

            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

This worked for me:

```
func loadImageFromURL(URL: NSURL) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL as URL)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let imageData = data {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I had to add "DispatchQueue.main.async { }" because I had a runtime warning, since only the main thread is supposed to modify UI elements.