# cannot convert value of type '(NSURLResponse!, NSData!, NSError!) - Void' to expected argument type '(NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void'

Tags: swift2

I'm trying to handle a completed URL request in Swift 2.2 and check for errors but the line starting with `completionHandler:{(response: NSURLResponse...` in the code below is throwing the error:

> cannot convert value of type '(NSURLREsponse!, NSData!, NSError!) - Void' to expected argument type '(NSURLResponse?, NSData?, NSError?) -> Void'.

I have a suspicion I need to use a do-try-catch but I'm not certain if there's a simpler way or not.

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
    completionHandler: {
        (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) - > Void in
        if error == nil {
            var image = UIImage(data: data)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                cell.selfieImgView.image = image
            })
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })

return cell
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your closure signature must match the signature expected by

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest()
```

Define it like the error message suggest:

```
completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in ...
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks Rasmus you rock! I'd be upvoting but I don't have a level 15 reputation yet

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know what the reason they've changed from the bang ! in Swift 1 to the ? in Swift 2 is would you?

Comment: No, but maybe you should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935304/sendasynchronousrequest-was-deprecated-in-ios-9-how-to-alter-code-to-fix