# HTTP Get receive JSonObjects Swift DebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm getting an issue while sending an HTTP GET command to a server to retrieve JSONObjects.

here is the command:

```
        if let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://11.22.33.44:8080/SRV/getAllUsers?owner=\(User.sharedInstance.email)") {
        print("\nSending URL: \(url)")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{
            (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?)-> Void in


            print("Response: \(response) \n")

            do{

                var datastring = NSString(data:data!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String?
                print("Data: \(datastring)")

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

             print("Json: \(json)")

            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }

        });
```

I received a HTTP 200 with all header information, but I'm trying to print NSData as String (nil) and also trying to retrieve my JSONObjects, I get the following message:

> Data: nil
>   Error with Json: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

I'm managing the server part, the servlet which is preparing JSONObjects is doing the following:

```
ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());   
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("id","1234");
objOut.writeObject(jsonObj);
objout.flush();
jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("id","5678");
objOut.writeObject(jsonObj);
objout.flush();
```

and a last important information, I'm able to retrieve those JSONObject from an Android application without any problem but it seems the format expected in swift for JSONObjects are not the same...

## EDIT

I changed the way to send HTTP GET command by using NSURLSession but before treating the JSONObject, I'm trying at least to display data as String:

```
typealias Payload = [String: AnyObject]

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://11.22.33.44:8080/SRV/getAllUsers?owner=\(User.sharedInstance.email)")
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if(error == nil)
            {
                let err : NSError! = nil

                    print("Response \(response)")

                    guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
                        print("error")
                        return
                    }

                    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                    print("Data: \(dataString)")

                    var json: Payload!

                    // 1
                    do {
                        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as? Payload
                        print("JSon: \(json)")
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                        //XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.finishExecution()
                    }



            }
            else
            {
                print(error?.description)
            }

        }
        task.resume()
```

I Received a HTTP 200 with the right header information, so I'm sure the servlet is successfully called, but get nil in data

> Data: nil
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

## EDIT #2

by using the following line

```
guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error data")
            return
        }

        print("data: \(data?.debugDescription)")
```

I can retrieve the following:

> data: Optional("OS_dispatch_data: data[0x7fc68bc45380] = { composite, size = >1067, num_records = 5 record[0] = { from = 0, length = 404, data_object = >0x7fc68bc999d0 }, record[1] = { from = 0, length = 135, data_object = >0x7fc68be1f830 }, record[2] = { from = 0, length = 264, data_object = >0x7fc68bc99a80 }, record[3] = { from = 0, length = 133, data_object = >0x7fc68bf97c20 }, record[4] = { from = 0, length = 131, data_object = >0x7fc68bca0b40 }, }>")

means I am able to retrieve data (at least!) but I don't know how I can extract from this data my JSONObject....

## SOLUTION

I finally found my problem.
server part needs to prepare JSONObject like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
// Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json object to the output stream      
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
// Assuming your json object is **jsonObject**, perform the following, it will return your json object  
out.print(jsonObject);
out.flush();
```

instead of using ObjectOutPutStream.

Swift part can retrieve it like this:

```
let url_to_request = "http://11.22.33.44:8080/SRV/getAllUsers?owner=\(User.sharedInstance.email)"

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url_to_request)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
    request.timeoutInterval = 10


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error data")
            return
        }


        var json: AnyObject?

    do
    {
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])


        for anItem in json as! [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
            let nom = anItem["nom"] as! String
            let prenom = anItem["prenom"] as! String
            let id = anItem["id"] as! String
            print("nom: \(nom) prenom: \(prenom) id: \(id)")
        }

    }
    catch
    {
        print("error Serialization")
        return
    }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Comment: sendAsynchronousRequest was deprecated in iOS 9.0. I suggest you use the dataTaskWithRequest method instead. Here have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30935460/5654848)

Comment: thanks dershowitz123, I know...but I never succeeded by using something else (as I'm new to Swift) still get an error, at least I would like to understand where is the formatting error I have as it works perfectly on Android....

Comment: Did it work or no? I'm confused. 

Comment: I would recommend you try Alamofire. An absolutely BRILLIANT library to deal with HTTP requests. And then try swiftyJSON to help you deal with JSON properly. Give it a shot. Come back and ask if u don't understand what to do. I'll help you out. :)

Comment: `Invalid value around character 0` means the JSON is invalid, the first character isn't `[` or `{` as expected.

Comment: I also tried with Alamofire but get the same error....I assume I have a problem on JSON formatting but in that case why does it work on Android ? I can retrieve correctly my JSONObjects on android starting by {. I'm using net.sf.JSONOBject on server side, may be the formatting is different than the one expected on IOS ?