# HTTPS Web Service in iOS App

Tags: php, ios, json, web-services, https

I have web services made in PHP which gives response in JSON. I have used these services in one of my iOS app.

But when I use web debugging tool like fiddler it shows all the data passing to my web services. Either I used GET or POST method.

How to secure the communication between server and the client application? Also which kind of encryption should be used to secure the data and where it should be used like either on server side or client side?

I have seen some methods like ssl/https connectivity to secure data. But I don't know how to implement that in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Secure web service data you many people follow below authentication procedures

Basic Authentication, [Authentication with NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest with completion handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828060/authentication-with-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequest-with-completion-hand)

OAuth 2.0,
https://github.com/nxtbgthng/OAuth2Client

SSL and TLS Authentication procedures
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-https-certificate-handling-to-protect-your-ios-app/

Before you implement in iOS ,your backend developer (in your case PHP Developer) need to implement in the backend side and provide necessary information to you

Answer (score 1):

If you use https all data is encrypted except the URL address. Some diagnostic programs can show the unencrypted communication by setting up a proxy on the device, this and MITM attacks can be averted by pinning the certificate if you are connecting to a known https server.